# Sort Struct records

Tags: c, sorting, struct

I have a structure that contains a field for student names. I'd like to order the names alphabetically. Here is the list of names that are stored into the name field of the structure:

```
Thui Bhu
Ariana B. Smith
Emily Gonzales
Jennifer L
Maria Jones
Bill Gates
Escobar Morris
Anne Latner
```

Here is the way I am defining the structure:

```
struct studentData {
        char name[30];
        int quiz1; int quiz2;
        int quiz3; int quiz4;
        int mid1; int mid2;
        int finalexam;
    } ;
```

Here is the code I have tried using to sort:

```
void SortNames(struct studentData *record, int reccount)
{
    int j,i;
    struct studentData temp;
    for(i = 1; i < reccount; i++)
    {
        j = i - 1;
        while( j >= 0 && strcmp( record[j+1].name, record[j].name) < 0 )
        {
            temp =  record[j + 1]; /*errors*/
            record[j+1] = record[j];
            record[j] = temp; /*errors*/
            j--;
        }
        printf("%s",record[j].name);
    }
   return;
}
```

This is the output that I am getting:

```
Ariana B. SmithEmily GonzalesJennifer LAriana B. SmithEmily Gonzales
```

Please help! I am open to using any built-in functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `qsort()`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int cmp(const void *l, const void *r)
{
    return strcmp(((struct studentData*)l)->name, ((struct studentData*)r)->name);
}

void SortNames(struct studentData *record, int reccount)
{
    int i;
    qsort(record, reccount, sizeof(struct studentData), cmp);
    for (i = 0; i < reccount; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", record[i].name);
    }
}
```

Comment: 2 questions: 1) do I declare the int cmp() function in my main? 2) what if I wanted to sort all the other record fields to match the order of the names?

Comment: 1. Declare and implement it outside any function, before `SortNames()`; 2. The whole struct is moved together when sorting, so the other fields is already matched.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need to create your own sort routine, the best approach is probably using the `qsort` function to sort the structs by `name`. When using `qsort` your task is simply to create a comparator funciton that takes a `void` pointer to type `struct studentData` and creates a way to compare by the member of interest (here `name`)

The `qsort` comparison funciton returns type int. For your struct it would look something like:

```
/* qsort struct comparision function (struct studentData by name) */
int struct_cmp_by_name (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    struct studentData *ia = (struct studentData *)a;
    struct studentData *ib = (struct studentData *)b;
    return strcmp (ia->name, ib->name);
}
```

(Note - you don't have qutie enough code posted to be exact, but it will be close to being) called in your code as:

```
qsort (record, number_structs, sizeof (struct studentData), struct_cmp_by_name);
```

This will sort `records` by the member `name`.